# Ember.Select optionValuePath doesnt work with collection ids

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Im filtering a list according to select's value, but it only works if i filter by string. If i try to use id's it wont work.
Here is two JsBin to demonstrate the problem:

this doestn work:

http://jsbin.com/EveQOke/70/edit

And here is the work around:

http://jsbin.com/EveQOke/71/edit

first i set the value path to a string, and i filter the list by name. filterProperty doestn like ids?

some code:
**template**

```
  {{view Ember.Select
      value=selectedCountry
      content=countries
      optionValuePath="content.id"
      optionLabelPath="content.name"
      prompt="Select Country"
  }}
```

**js**

```
  filtered: (function() {
    console.log(this.get('selectedCountry'));
    return this.get('list').filterProperty('country.id', this.get('selectedCountry'));
  }).property('selectedCountry')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it can also filter by ID, the thing here is that the ids here:

```
countries : [
  {id:'1',name:'Sierre Leone'},
  {id:'2',name:'Japan'}
]
```

are strings, and here:

```
list : [
  {id:'1',country:{id:1,name:'Sierre Leone'},nr:'234'},
  {id:'2',country:{id:1,name:'Sierre Leone'},nr:'674'},
  {id:'3',country:{id:2,name:'Japan'},nr:'934'},
  {id:'4',country:{id:2,name:'Japan'},nr:'243'}
]
```

you put the countries' ids as integers, they need to have the same type, so you either change de 'countries' property to have integers or the countries inside list to have strings.